# how to safely pass variable in php with url rewriting?

Tags: php, variables, url, url-rewriting

i have a list of linked thumbnails. Each thumbnail has a link with one variable.

```
<a href="index.php?id=1"><img src="thumb1.jpg">
<a href="index.php?id=2"><img src="thumb2.jpg">
```

etc...

now, i've updated site to use url rewriting. Idea is that i have links like this

```
<a href="gallery/?id=1"><img src="thumb1.jpg">
<a href="gallery/?id=2"><img src="thumb2.jpg">
```

or something simillar.

On the landing page, i use `$id` to execute `MySQL` query and show all pictures from gallery with that id.

```
$pictures = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_gallery where id=$id",$db);
```

Can it be done, and main thing, how can i prevent that passing id poses a security threat?

Cheers,
Aleks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url-rewriting part does not itself really introduce any new security-threats, the issue is the usage of `mysql_*` functions (which are deprecated) and not escaping the `$id` request-variable.

If you are scared of SQL-Injections (as one should be), either escape the $id variable before using it in the query or rather use prepared statements (and then switch to either mysqli or PDO, which you should do in any case cause of mysql_* being deprecated!).

Always validate and escape anything that you are about to use in a database query.

Comment: how can i escape it? i'm not very familliar with this...
I don't enter anything into db, just read, but i am, as you say, afraid of sql injections.

Other thing, when i use gallery/?id=2 as link, varibale is NOT passed to other file. How can i do it ?

Comment: Well, without seeing your rewrite-rules (probably in the .htaccess file) I cant help with why the param is not passed. I would again recommend moving over to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statments, no need to escape in that case. But if you are sticking to the deprecated mysql functions, the `mysql_real_escape_string` function is probably what you are looking for. if you expect the $id to be a number, you could always check with `if(is_numeric($id))`, cause if it is, you don't really have to escape it. Sql injections applies to any type of query, not only inserts.

Comment: yes, it will always be numeric. is_numeric function addes, mysqli added.
I just need to pass the variable :). rewrite works (yes, in htaccess) so when it finds particular page ID it rewrites url
for example index.php?page_id=300 becomes /gallery-thumbs/ and index.php?page_id=301 becomes /gallery/. Now, i just need to pass id form /gallery-thumbs/ to /gallery/

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it gave you the information you where after! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection.) and make sure you sanitize any user input or consider using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

For a particular implementation I leave this encapsulated piece of code

```
function ControllerAction($id=null) {
  // I like to formalize on entry; this is supposed to be an absolute integer and nothing else
  $id = abs((int)$id);
  $q = 'SELECT * FROM t_gallery where id = ?'; // placeholder
  // use PDO, it's safe and very comfortable
  $pdo = get_pdo_connection($whatever_you_need);
  // prepare it because it has placeholders, and because there is external input comming in
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($q);
  // execute it
  $stmt->execute(array($id)); // read the reference documentation to understand this clearly
  // now the stmt object holds the results
  return $stmt->fetchObject();// whatever you like here, I like to make a DAO
}
```

In this example that simple incomming parameter has already been prepared for use but I still use prepared statements for consistency (my own code convention)

**Alert:** This uses some form of half-assed MVC/MVP/MVVM (I'm not sure anymore) type architecture

- you could actually make your href URLs like this if you are using **Url Rewriting** to further implement your SEO links

  ```
  protocol://host/controller/action/getParam1/getParam2
  // usage
  http://yourhost/browsethumbs/aNumber
  ```